# Cannot change color of icon that is in a button in Android studio

Tags: xml, themes

I've added two buttons to the linear layout and space between them, I've changed the colors of the icons in the drawable map but it still shows them in my primary color.

[Picture of buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrGyI.jpg)

My XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
  android:gravity="bottom">

<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/baseline_cancel_24"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="cancel"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
    android:textColor="@android:color/transparent" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/baseline_check_24"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/green"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="confirm"
    android:textColor="@android:color/transparent" />
```

My themes:

```
<style name="Theme.PoliceTracker" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `android` use `app` in this line

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
```

like this,

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/red"
```

It will change the color.